# jQuery add class and remove it for all the elements who doesnt have it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a system, to make the user select a table row by itself, then press the delete button to delete it.

So i made this:

```
$("#container tbody tr").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow");
});

function delete() {
    var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
    if (check) {
         $(".selectedRow").remove();
    }
}

$("#delete-btn").click(delete);
```

And for the CSS:

```
#container tbody tr.selectedRow {
   background-color: red; 
}
```

So i'm trying to achieve, when i click a `table row` inside the `tbody` that it gives the `selectedRow` class to it, but it removes the class of any other element in that same container.

How do i make it so that i can only select one `tr` (table row)?

**My own try**:

```
$("#container tbody tr").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow");
    $(this).parent().removeClass("selectedRow");
});
```

But that didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#container tbody tr").click(function () {

    // Remove selectedRow class from any rows having it in this table
    $('.selectedRow', $(this).parent()).removeClass("selectedRow");

    // Add it to the clicked row
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow");

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems much cleaner then the other answers and better explaination. Accepting when i can.

Comment: Works, but over complicated unless you are using generic class name, and want to restrict to one object. Otherwise just use plain jQuery class selector, as with @Anoop Joshi

Answer (score 3):

Do like this

```
$("#container tbody tr").click(function () {
    $(".selectedRow").removeClass("selectedRow");
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow");

});
```

First line will remove the class name of `selectedRow` from all elements. Then you can add the class to clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
$("#container tbody tr").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".selectedRow").removeClass("selectedRow");
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow");
});
```

Comment: I would stick with the other version that removes "selectedRow" from every element , then add .  It helps a lot for clicking really fast and slow browsers.  Just all around better IMO

Comment: What if there are other elements with that class that shouldn't lose it?  There could be multiple tables.  This follows the pattern that the OP shows of removing that class from only the table in question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your managing function to this:

```
$("#container tbody tr").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".selectedRow").removeClass("selectedRow");
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow");
});
```

Comment: Aye', its kind of the same as the one from @techfoobar right? But this one is using `.find()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container tbody tr").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("selectedRow").siblings().removeClass("selectedRow");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container tbody tr").click(function () {

 // Remove selectedRow class from any rows having it in this table
 $(".selectedRow").removeClass("selectedRow");

 // Add it to the clicked row
 $(this).addClass("selectedRow");

});
```